# View multiple remote desktops at the same time in Debian

Tags: debian, unix, remote-desktop

I would like to be able to view multiple remote desktops at the same time.  All the machines are running Debian.  Ideally, if I could get the view on a windows machine that would be perfect.  However, if the solution is only for a Debian, that would also be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instal xrdp (`sudo apt-get install xrdp`) on the remote machines.

You can view it on windows using the regular RDP client and on Linux you can install a XRDP client like Remmina for example (it's in Ubuntu repo, not sure in Debian) (`apt-get install remmina`)

[remmina site](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/downloads.shtml)

Comment: Why go to the trouble/expense of a MSWidows client? Using vnc or nx you can do it with all sorts of clients. With xnest you don't even need custom server software. Indeed unless you explicitly want to to get access to the desktop on the remote machines rather than just displaying their windows locally, the X window system was explicitly designed with this in mind.

Comment: @laurent thanks for the answer.  I gave it a spin.  It does work, but it launches another instance of the desktop (lxde).  Is there a way to go into the "current" desktop?

Comment: @symcbean Because it's OP wish to view it in windows if possible. Anyways, xrdp is a lot easier and smaller than nx and it works a lot better than vnc and nx in my experience. (as far as last time I tested, nx didn't work with unity in ubuntu and is a lot slower than xrdp)

Comment: @Scoop I don't know any way to go to the current desktop because you make a new login but there may be one... on Ubuntu there is a desktop viewer that shows the current desktop to another ubuntu machine. Maybe there is something similiar in debian?

Comment: @symcbean what is the difference between xrdp, tightnvc, and x11vnc?

Comment: @symcbean xrdp is not a MSWindow client, it is the same as nxserver + nxnode (or vnc server) for xrdp protocol. Remmina also is not a windows software, it is a linux gtk client able to view remote machines using xrdp and vnc protocols (same as nxclient with more options). Anyways, I down understand the downvote... expense?? all are free (not the case of nomachine nx where the free edition only allows 2 simultaneous connections). Trouble: single apt-get install, no config... a lot easier than nx wich is in your suggestion... Remmina can see vnc servers and easily make ssh tunnels.

Comment: @Scoop - to interact with the current desktop then (AFAIK) VNC is the only option other than passive traffic sniffing (i.e. view only). xrdp is an open-source implementation of the propretary protocol implemented (in very different ways) by Microsoft and Citrix, Tightvnc is a derivative of the open-source VNC protocol supported on all sorts of clients and servers. X11vnc is a VNC client designed to run on the XWindow system

Comment: @laurent I never said xrdp was a MSWindows client - there is no xrdp protocol - there's a family of protocols collectively known as RDP. Downvote? Because there's lots of different answers and yours is very specific.

Comment: @symcbean, humm so I think I misunderstood what was that for "Why go to the trouble/expense of a MSWidows client?". True the protocol is rdp, not xrdp. Specific answer? Well isn't that the best way to answer objectively a question? A generic answer like "use a vnc/rdp server and a vnc/rdp client" wouldn't have been very useful I guess and listing all the options is what are the other answers slots for (and we can't see any filled until now...). I didn't pretend writing a paper on "how to connect multiple remote hosts viewing their screens" here, I only showed one I use and works best for me.